# UndefVarError in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Very new to Julia and trying to work through some code. I keep getting this error: "ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: @defVar not defined". The start of the code is below where I define the @defVar.  Julia Version 1.1.1 (2019-05-16). Here is the code I am using:

```
using DataFrames
using GLPKMathProgInterface
using JuMP

num_lineups = 6
num_overlap = 4

path_data = "/users/matt/desktop/example_players.csv"
path_data2 = "/users/matt/desktop/example_players2.csv"
path_to_output= "/users/matt/desktop/output.csv"

m = Model(solver=GLPKSolverMIP())
    @defVar(m, players_a_lineup[i=1:num_players_a], Bin)
    @defVar(m, players_b_lineup[i=1:num_players_b], Bin)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and Julia! The tutorial/doc/code you are using is probably very old. I think `@defVar` no longer exists in newer versions of JuMP. You can use `@variable` and try a recent tutorial/doc instead such as [JuMP examples](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl/tree/master/examples) or [JuliaOpt notebooks](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/juliaopt-notebooks/).

Comment: Those resources were a tremendous help... thank you!

Comment: @hckr Make that an answer and let RebirdFan23 close the question?

Comment: @MarcusRitt ... new to stack, can I close it?

Comment: You have to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). I have just added one, but you could wait a bit for @hckr to add his, and accept it, otherwise accept mine. Then the question will be "officially" answered.

Comment: Please go ahead with @MarcusRitt 's answer. If an answer is a solution to your problem, click to the checkmark next to the answer. Accepting an answer is not mandatory but it would be considered extremely good to accept the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old syntax (`@defvar` has been used up to version 0.12). For the latest [Julia/JuMP](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/v0.19.1/quickstart) version 19, your code could should read

```
using DataFrames
using GLPK
using JuMP
...
m = Model(with_optimizer(GLPK.Optimizer))
@variable(m, players_a_lineup[i=1:num_players_a], Bin)
@variable(m, players_b_lineup[i=1:num_players_b], Bin)
```